# What does the bracket way of showing error means?

Tags: standard-error

The value of avagadro number is given in my book as 6.02217(4). Does this mean 6.022174 or 6.02214?
Even some numbers have (12) like two digit numbers. Also what is this notation called? Why is it used for? Can't they use percentage or absolute errors?

Comment: I would read it as an absolute error based on a multiple (in brackets) of the least significant digit shown in the main result so in your example  $6.02217\pm0.00004$ so between $6.02213$ and $6.02221$

Comment: See the paragaph starting "In the last notation, parentheses are the concise notation ..." at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty#Measurements

Comment: Thanks. I think it is used contract things a little bit to look nice